# UVOutline Problem when texture

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

[image]https://gyazo.com/5cf6c595588ae0348db013e1f8bec38f

So that's what happened, the UV outlines show when the mesh is  rendered from a distance or an angle, the texture image is jpg, I've tied raising the bleed value, but it still didn't work, any help?

Comment: Hello :). I'd recommend adding some images directly into the post. Not everyone is going to click the link.

Comment: sure, thanks :D